Have a group of Catholics ever petitioned the Vatican to remove troubling passages from the Bible?
Have a group of Catholics ever petitioned the Vatican to remove troubling passages from the Bible?
If a present-day human authored passages like Deuteronomy 22:28-29 or Isaiah 14:21, there would be serious blowback on social media and the author would likely be cancelled for life.

While a negative cannot be proved, it's possible that someone at some point vainly and foolishly attempted to do so, but it's unlikely the Vatican ever took it seriously.

@eques: So why do the human authors of the Bible get a pass but present-day humans do not?

Huh? Get a pass for what?

@eques: If a modern author wrote that rubbish, they'd be cancelled for life; but the Bible is a sacred text, inspired by God - so leave it in there for cultural context. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Frankly, your opinions is laughable. The modern world doesn't cancel things consistently based upon any high standards of intellectual quality, let alone artistic quality. Furthermore, your understanding of the relationship between the Vatican, Catholics and Scripture is entirely backwards and contradictory.

@eques Different question - If you don't endorse Deuteronomy 22:28-29 and Isaiah 14:21, then why should we keep those passages in the sacred Bible?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@JimG. You seem to be under a misapprehension about what the Bible is and how it works. I've written a few sentences in chat which I hope will help you.
